How to make Google Sheets data load faster when embedded in a Web App?
I have a small Web App that sends data to a Google Sheets file.
I need to display the value of a single cell of this file on my page. This is because I am not storing the data in my database.
I have managed to do it but I realized that the value sometimes is not loading.
I noticed that if I add some restrictions (like restrict the API to my specific domain) the value is not loaded at all.
I want to add that I am doing it in Wordpress in my custom theme and I am loading the API in my functions.php and then rendering the data using a shortcode on the frontend.
function sheet_value_shortcode($atts) {
$API = 'MY_API';  
$google_spreadsheet_ID = 'ID_Google_Sheets';  // Replace with your Google Sheets ID
$api_key = esc_attr($API);

    $location = $atts['location'];

    // Append a unique timestamp to the URL to prevent caching
    $unique_identifier = time(); // Generate a unique timestamp
    $get_cell = new WP_Http();
    $cell_url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/$google_spreadsheet_ID/values/$location?&key=$api_key&_=$unique_identifier"; 
    $cell_response = $get_cell->get($cell_url);
    $json_body = json_decode($cell_response['body'], true); 
    $cell_value = $json_body['values'][0][0];

    return $cell_value;
    }


What's the question? How to make your internet connection faster?

no, actually not. I just noticed that if I add some restrictions to my API key this value is not rendered at all so I think is an implementation error from my side.
This is why I asked.

So where is your restrictions being added? What error you get?

Copy of Google Sheets cell value not always rendered on my Web App. See Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites.
